# Can't show html using Flask

Tags: python, flask, path

So I have been trying to get used to Flash in python but I've come across a problem. I want that when `http://localhost:5000/` is inserted in the browser a html page is displayed. I've tried multiple ways to do this like using the `render_template()` but that returns me a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`. I've also tried a simple `return redirect()` but that throws something saying the adress was not recognized or understood. When I tried using the `url_for()` it threw 404 - not found. I really have no idea how to fix this.

```
# htppserver.py

import flask
import threading

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="Dashboard/website")

@app.route("/site", methods=["GET"])
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def get_site():
    return render_template("index.html")


x = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
x.start()
```

Currently my dir system looks something like this

```
main_folder # This is the working directory accordingly to os.getcwd()
├──cogs
│     └──httpserver.py # Source code is here
└──Dashboard
           └website
                  ├──...
                  ├──index.html # This is the file I want to show
                  └──...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your html files in a folder called "templates" in the same directory as the python file that serves

Comment: Great. It loads the page but now it's not correctly displayed because I get `127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2021 20:35:58] "GET /index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -` and `127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2021 20:35:58] "GET /main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -` which means the page doesn't have neither css nor javascript lol. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: yes, you should read on the file structure, and how flask treats styling files, js files, and html files. Not quite sure for js but my website has a folder called "static" in the same dir as the py file, and inside the static folder there are "styles" and "images" folders, used respectively